# Finding vectors in a hexagon

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is a regular hexagon. I am supposed to find CD. I failed. I don't know how this happened.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For your regular hexagon, $\vec{AD}=2\vec{FE}$

Comment: Thanks! This helped. So, I'm not allowed to use FA because it is unknown and because I would always get infinitely many solutions?

Comment: I agree: Finding FA is any easier than finding CD.  It seems to me that for this problem you have to use the geometry of the regular hexagon to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, $DE + EF + FA + AC = DC$, not $CD$.

Comment: it should be a comment, not an answer !

Comment: Yes, my mistake, but when I go the other way around I get CD = CD which means infinitely many solutions, but that should not be the case, right?

Comment: @idm: The question was, "I failed.  I don't know how this happened."  I was pointing out an error (maybe not the only one) that caused this to happen.